# Можно ли для разработки и отладки имитировать смартфон на PC

Tags: android, мобильная-разработка, мобильные-приложения, kivy

Добрый день.

Начал изучать `kivy` и столкнулся с тем, что некоторые фичи не могу предварительно протестировать на компьютере.

Каждый раз приходится билдить apk-файл, заливать его на телефон, инсталлировать и проверять там. Если написанный код нужно отлаживать, то это вообще превращается в кошмар.

Сейчас такое происходит в основном когда я пишу код, связанный с геолокацией, но, подозреваю, что в будущем мне захочется использовать ещё и гироскопический датчик и некоторые другие специфичные для смартфона вещи.

Есть ли возможность имитировать на компьютере все эти датчики, чтобы можно было заниматься отладкой без плясок с бубном?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще то большинство нормальных сенсоров можно симулировать на эмуляторе. Даже датчик отпечатков пальцев.

Если виртуальное устройство не поддерживает их эмуляцию, то можно установить [SensorEmulator](https://github.com/openintents/sensorsimulator) и получить желаемое...

С другой стороны, конечно, физическое устройство всегда лучше чем виртуальное. Тем более, что некоторые физические устройства умеют эмулировать изменение показаний своих сенсоров - например симулировать локацию (почти у всех Samsung'ов есть такие девелоперские фичи).

**Update**

В комплект поставки Android Studio входит т.н. Android Virtual Device Manager - [подробнее здесь](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html)

Есть еще сторонние разработки, самая известная это [Geny Motion](https://www.genymotion.com) - который базируется на [Oracle VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org)

Более-менее стандартный паттерн разработки, это когда сначала проводится тестирование на виртуальном устройстве и только потом на физических устройствах.

Comment: А можете подробнее рассказать про виртуальные устройства? Просто я мобильной разработкой тоько на днях интересоваться начал, до этого мой опыт в программировании ограничивался бэк-ендом и скриптами.

Comment: см. апдейт ответа

Answer (score 1):

Да, можно, Вам необходим любой эмулятор андроида для ПК. Они все бесплатные и все позволяют эмуляцию различных датчиков и GPS. Установка apk-файлов на них может осуществляться как через утилиту для командой строки (или через IDE), так и простым перетягиванием apk-файлика.

Самый популярный, вероятно, Android Virtual Devices он идёт вместе с Android SDK (или с Android Studio). Почитать о нём можно [здесь](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html). К сожалению недавно standalone установка стала сложнее и проще [скачать бандл](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) из эмулятора, студии и SDK.

Долгое врeмя был популярен [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/download-trial/) -- первый массовый x86 эмулятор. Раньше у него был бесконечный free trial для некоммерческого использования. Есть standalone установка, требует наличия virtualbox.

Если Вам по какой-то причине очень нужен Hyper-V, то ни один из вышеперечисленных вариантов работать не будет, зато будет работать эмулятор Android для Visual Stuido. Он может быть установлен вместе с бесплатной Community версией IDE, подробнее о нём [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/mt228279.aspx).

Сейчас особой разницы в возможностях и производительности нет, но учтите, что последние два эмулятора используют образы с х86 архитектурой, так что если Вы используете С/С++ библиотеки в своей разработке (это вряд ли, разве что у вас обработка видео/изображений), то Вам потребуется х86 версия библиотеки для эмулятора и ARM-версия для реальных устройств или поискать ARM to x86 транслятор для конкретного эмулятора.

Comment: android emulator из android SDK (AVD) отлично работает с ARM образами без всякого транслятора, хотя и медленее, чем с x86

Comment: Мне казалось, что с переходом на новый эмулятор они оставили только x86 образы. Давно им не пользовался, так как вынужден использоваться эмулятор от Visual Stuido.